# Rewrite files up a directory and remove file extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

I need to rewrite files up a directory and remove the file extension

I have something like

```
https://example.com/dir/file.svg
```

and I want to rewrite the URL to

```
https://example.com/file
```

Here's my current code, which only removes the `.svg`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.svg -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.svg [L]
```

I'm only getting started with this web server stuff, so sorry if it sounds weird or anything

Comment: "I want to rewrite the URL to `https://example.com/file`" - Presumably you mean to `/file.svg`? (Your current rule rewrites the request from `/file` to `/file.svg` - it _appends_ the `.svg` file extension, it does not _remove_ it. You have presumably already removed the file extension in the initial request?)

Comment: yes, and yes the code i gave already does that

Comment: i'm asking how to make it go up a directory

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is still unclear as written. It makes no sense to "rewrite" the request from `/dir/file.svg` to `/file`. That could possibly be a "redirect", but that is not what your current rule is doing and without a corresponding rewrite in the other direction that will not work. You could "rewrite" from `/file` to `/dir/file.svg`, but that is _down_ a directory, not "up" as your Q is asking? Can you please clarify what the URL is you are requesting and the file-path you are expecting to be served? Is `/dir` a filesystem directory or simply a URL path-segment?

Comment: as i said in the original question, i'm only getting started with this web server stuff, so i don't know everything. as i also said in the original question, i want `https://example.com/file` to have the file content of  `https://example.com/dir/file.svg`. `/dir` is a filesystem directory. so, i mean i want to rewrite down a directory and add a `.svg` file extension. is that clear now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it is... very easy to tell.